# why firebase functions onCall not deploy?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i have typescript code in index.ts

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as cors from "cors";

cors({ origin: true });

exports.myFunc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const { uid } = context.auth;

  return { uid };
});
```

If i try deploy this function:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:myFunc
```

I get back:

> functions: the following filters were specified but do not match any
>   functions in the project: myFunc

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: So you're putting TypeScript code in a file that ends with .js?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @DougStevenson `import` and `export` are not typescript code it's `es6` syntax

Comment: @AhmedM.Kamal That's not the issue.  Depending on the configuration (which they're not showing), this file may never get transpiled, and may never get picked up by the deployer.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry, i made a typo. correct index.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found a mistake. Typescript compile my .js files in directory `lib/functions/src/index.js` but my package.json file have outher path to main file

```
{
  ...
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  ...
}
```

i changed to

```
{
  ...
  "main": "lib/functions/src/index.js",
  ...
}
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
// index.js

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors');

cors({ origin: true });

exports.myFunc = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const { uid } = context.auth;
  return { uid };
});
```

then `$ firebase deploy --only functions`